# Passing an array from

Tags: c++

Hi I am attempting to create a chess board to reintroduce myself to c++. I am having trouble with adding a member function to my array that the chess board is located in. 
I believe I am structuring the problem incorrectly.

.cpp file:

```
#include "spaces.h"
#include <iostream>

char board::spaceLetter() {
    return letter;
}

char board::spaceNumber() {
    return number;
}

string board::getColor(board a) {
    if (a.color() == true) //Also an error but not a big deal
        return "black";
    else
        return "white";
}

void board::printBoard(board a[][8]) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
            if (a[i][j].color() == true) { //This is where my problem is
                cout << "w";
            }
            else
                cout << "b";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Header .h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class board {
    private: 
        int boardSpace[8][8];
        bool color; 
        char number;
        char letter;

    public:
        board(){
            for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
                    if (((i + j) % 2) == 0)
                        color = true; //black space
                    else
                        color = false; 
                }
            }
        }
        char spaceLetter();
        char spaceNumber();
        string getColor(board);

        void printBoard(board a[][8]);
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem like passing arrays into your member functions is useful or desirable. It looks like you just want to be printing and getting the `boardSpace` member.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `getColor()`? Although that returns a `string` and you're comparing it with a `bool`

Comment: I am curious why the method `printBoard()` isn't just accessing the `boardSpace` array that is a private member of the `board` class rather than taking an argument that is an array of class `board`. It looks to me like there is a bit of a mixup about a single 8x8 board and an array of 8x8 boards each of which is 8x8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

`if (a.color() == true) //Also an error but not a big deal`

**color** is not a function. It is a member variable. Remove the `()` from `color()`.

Same mistake here:

```
if (a[i][j].color() == true)
```

Try running the code here and see if it works for you: https://rextester.com/GRG48268

Comment: Thank you! I aplogize for asking such a stupid question

Comment: There are no stupid questions. But try to dig into the problem a bit more next time. I'm sure you would have seen this error yourself.